# Use one namespace prefix for 2 different namespaces

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Is it possible to use one namespace prefix to describe 2 different namespaces

```
<html xmlns:my="http://namespace1/" xmlns:my="http://namespace2/" />

<my:component1> comes from namespace 1 </my:component1>
<my:component2> comes from namespace 2 </my:component2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer (well, short answer padded out because StackOverflow does not allow short answers): No.